# Unable to Install PHP Zip Module via Docker Build

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, php-7, gcloud

I'm running into an issue with Docker images. I'm using the base image `FROM ubuntu:16.04`, and installing the following packages on it:

```
RUN apt-get -y install apache2
RUN apt-get -y install php7.0
RUN apt-get -y install libapache2-mod-php7.0
RUN apt-get -y install php7.0-mysql
RUN apt-get -y install php7.0-gd
RUN apt-get -y install php-pear
RUN apt-get -y install php7.0-curl
RUN apt-get -y install php7.0-mbstrin
RUN apt-get -y install php-imagick
RUN apt-get -y install curl
RUN apt-get -y install lynx-cur
RUN apt-get -y install php7.0-zip
#RUN apt-get -y install php7.0-xsl
```

Long story, I need the `php7.0-zip` package to install, but doing a `docker build -t [...] .` with the above packages noted results in an image that doesn't have `zip` installed/enabled. There are no errors during the command, and at a glance, everything seems to have gone ok.

Looking at the output of the command, I can see that it is properly downloading and attempting to install `libzip4` and `zip` (`libzip4`, or `zlib`, is a dependency that is installed along with `php7.0-zip`):

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libzip4 php7.0-zip 
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 56.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 186 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 libzip4 amd64 1.0.1-0ubuntu1 [36.3 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64  php7.0-zip amd64 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 [19.9 kB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 56.1 kB in 0s (123 kB/s)

Selecting previously unselected package libzip4:amd64.
(Reading database ... 13491 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libzip4_1.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libzip4:amd64 (1.0.1-0ubuntu1) ...

Selecting previously unselected package php7.0-zip.
Preparing to unpack .../php7.0-zip_7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0-zip (7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) ...
Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php7.0 (7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) ...
Processing triggers for php7.0-fpm (7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of restart.
Setting up libzip4:amd64 (1.0.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up php7.0-zip (7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/zip.ini with new version
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php7.0 (7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) ...
Processing triggers for php7.0-fpm (7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of restart.
---> fe12c0bd06fd
Removing intermediate container 7cadeb2256d0
```

There's a couple of notices, but nothing fails. After pushing to gcloud and downloading to a local project, running a `phpinfo()` after configuring and connecting to the image results in the following:

[image]

In this image, there is no `zip` module enabled. For reference, another, local installation of PHP that has `zip` enabled shows as this:

[image]

I've tried installing another packing following the same steps (`php7.0-xsl`) and after configuring and connecting, the `xsl` module is shown as enabled in `phpinfo()`:

[image]

Has anyone ever encountered this case before? I don't know why `zip` isn't installing and I'm at a loss... I need the `zip` module for `excel` related functions, but I'm not sure what to do next. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

If my whole Dockerfile is required, I will update.

Comment: Do you solve it? I have the same problem

Comment: Take a look at docker-php-ext-install (https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/docker-php-ext-install)

Comment: I have the same problem. It would be nice to get a solution for this

Comment: I tried with [phpdocker.io](https://phpdocker.io) They do have the zip in their [Dockerfile](https://github.com/phpdocker-io/base-images/blob/master/php/7.0/cli/Dockerfile) and when I try `php -i | grep zip` in the docker image I do have zip enabled. _(I tried with docker-compose/Dockerfile generated by their website. The Dockerfile shipped with PHP7.0 is also Ubuntu 16)_

Comment: Sorry, my edit was too late :(  it easier to see like this `php -i | grep enabled` and just in case, to open bash in the docker image: `docker exec -it yourContainerName-php-fpm /bin/bash`

Comment: What does `Additional .ini files parsed` section show?

Comment: To anyone asking for clarification/a solution from me, I've since lost access to this project and no longer use docker for builds and/or deployments. If the answer below is correct, please upvote it and I can accept and close this question.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I tested on the Dockerfile and it works:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -qq -y install curl
RUN apt-get -y install apache2
RUN apt-get -y install php7.0
RUN apt-get -y install libapache2-mod-php7.0
RUN apt-get -y install php7.0-mysql
RUN apt-get -y install php7.0-gd
RUN apt-get -y install php-pear
RUN apt-get -y install php7.0-curl
RUN apt-get -y install php7.0-mbstrin
RUN apt-get -y install php-imagick
RUN apt-get -y install curl
RUN apt-get -y install lynx-cur
RUN apt-get -y install php7.0-zip
```

After running:

```
docker build -t stackoverflow .

docker run -it stackoverflow bash
```

And finally `php -i | grep enabled` inside the container (where you will be after the docker run command is executed) I have it installed and enabled as you can see in the image (terminal window, bottom left)

[image: PHP Storm Dockerfile and terminal window]

As a side note you should normally use one `RUN` command to install multiple extensions in order to generate only one layer.